# Facebook Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Estou com seguinte erro não consegui uma solução:

> Error:(15, 0) Could not find property 'ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION' on
>   project ':facebook'.

Estou utilizando Android studio 1.2.2.

```
build.gradle:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.douglaswilliam.app_carona"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.1'
    compile project(':facebook')
}
```

resolvi da seguinte forma editei: compileSdkVersion 22 para compileSdkVersion 19 e buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3" para buildToolsVersion "21.0.0 rc3" e install build tools

Comment: [Essa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21477884/4056678), [essa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27617235/4056678), [essa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25394070/4056678) e [essa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24466921/4056678). Alguma resolve?

Comment: ja tentei não obteve sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A versão do SDK do facebook(`facebook-android-sdk:4.5.1`)  que você está usando não funciona para a versão SDK 9 do android que você estabeleceu no projeto na linha `minSdkVersion 9`

Veja outras versões do [SDK do facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads) ou aumente o valor do skd minimo do android.